# Firebase node library error crashes aws lambda without logging

Tags: node.js, lambda, firebase

Using firebase-queue and firebase node library to push data via aws lambda.  Sometimes I get the following error which occurs without any patterns(randomly). Totally blank on the issue, not able to debug since lambda process exists without any logs.

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'processIncomingMessage' of undefined at instance.processIncomingMessage (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/websocket_extensions.js:133:20) at instance._emitMessage (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:442:22) at instance._emitFrame (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:405:19) at instance.parse (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:144:18) at instance.parse (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/client.js:56:58) at IO.write (/var/task/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/streams.js:80:16) at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24) at flow (_stream_readable.js:611:7) at CleartextStream.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:643:5) at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:92:17) at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10) at _stream_readable.js:420:7 at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like the web socket disappears in the middle of an operation. If it is closed, the Firebase client should normally re-establish the connection. But I'm not sure if that's what happens here. Does the client where this happen fail to write data to the database at all?

Comment: Thanks for throwing light on it, yes it fails, the code is executed in lambda as soon as this happens lambda crashes without any log in even cloudwatch

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I was using firebase as a queue, there were random crashes which were not debuggable so had to remove it.
The conclusion I reached (may not be correct at all) in conjunction to Frank's comment above was that AWS was forcefully closing the websockets kept alive by firebase, especially when there was a spike in requests.
Maybe this could shed some more light 
[link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205761)